# meteor async issue on server only

Tags: javascript, meteor

so I have a method in the server folder like this:

```
dataHandler: function(id)
{
    var data;

    // here I call a server method
    Meteor.call('getData', id, function(err, result)
    {
        data = result;
    });

    // now I want to use data in another method
    Meteor.call('convertData', data, function(err, result)
    {
        data = result;
    });

    return data;
}
```

Now this does not work, as `data` when calling `Meteor.call('convertData' ... )` will be undefined. How would I do to make this work in meteor on the server side where I can't use Session.set/get?

Answer (score 1):

On the server you have an option to call methods synchronously.  If you do not supply a callback function that is the default.

> If you do not pass a callback on the server, the method invocation will block until the method is complete. It will eventually return the return value of the method, or it will throw an exception if the method threw an exception. - http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call

Your code should work just like this:

```
dataHandler: function(id) {
  var data = Meteor.call('getData', id );
  return Meteor.call('convertData', data );
}
```

Comment: `if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined` ... what does it mean to be inside a stub? I always get undefined on `data` when using this.

Comment: A stub is the client version of a method run for latency compensation.  Stubs are described at length at the beginning of the methods sections in the doc. The sentence you copied begins 'On the client,'.  Your question specifies being on the server.  If the method 'getData' returns undefined them maybe show that code also.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you call a http request on server without a callback it will no keep running. so if you write

```
data = Meteor.call('getData', id);

// now I want to use data in another method
Meteor.call('convertData', data, function(err, result)
{
    data = result;
});
```

it should work fine